# "SQL LIMIT" in php multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

How can I do something like

```
SELECT * from table LIMIT '10','50'
```

in a php multidimensional array?

Comment: Could you provide some input ?

Answer (score 3):

use array_slice http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

$data is your array

```
$myData = array_slice($data,10,50);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php).

```
<?php
$input = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");

$output = array_slice($input, 2);      // returns "c", "d", and "e"
$output = array_slice($input, -2, 1);  // returns "d"
$output = array_slice($input, 0, 3);   // returns "a", "b", and "c"

// note the differences in the array keys
print_r(array_slice($input, 2, -1));
print_r(array_slice($input, 2, -1, true));
?>
```

Because you didn't provided many details about your arrays, i can't provide better example than this one above.

```
//pseudo code
foreach($your_whole_array as $child_array) {
    $limited_array[] = array_slice($child_array, 0, 2);
}

//$limited_array now contains your limited data
```

Comment: hey, it is the details array : $array['post'] = array( array( Title => "rose", 
                      Price => 1.25,
                      Number => 15 
                    ),
               array( Title => "daisy", 
                      Price => 0.75,
                      Number => 25,
                    ),
               array( Title => "orchid", 
                      Price => 1.15,
                      Number => 7 
                    )
             );

Comment: Yeah, this is an array. But i don't know anything about your rules to apply on it. You can iterate through $array['post'] with foreach then slice every child array based on your rules.

Answer (score 0):

```
array array_slice ( array $array , int $offset [, int $length [, bool $preserve_keys = false ]] )
```

Comment: hey, it is the details array : 
$shop['entry'] = array( array( Title => "rose", 
                      Price => 1.25,
                      Number => 15 
                    ),
               array( Title => "daisy", 
                      Price => 0.75,
                      Number => 25,
                    ),
               array( Title => "orchid", 
                      Price => 1.15,
                      Number => 7 
                    )
             );

Comment: How did you tried? what `print_r(array_slice($shop['entry'],10,50));` produces?